# RegEx Javascript - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this pattern stored in a variable:

```
var regexServer = /^([0-9]{2,3})+\.([0-9]{2,3})+\.([0-9]{2,3})+\.([0-9]{2,3})+\:[0-9]{2,4}$/;

if(!stringFromArgument.match(regexServer))
   alert("You must input a valid IP and a Port address! Eg: 66.77.88.99:8000");
```

I checked the string coming from the input (form), and it's ok.

If somebody wants to add his own IP and Port address he must add a valid form. His string must contain only `.`, `:`, numbers and no whitespace.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide the example input you are usingthat is failing

Comment: Note that just one digit is perfectly normal in an IP address, e.g. `66.77.88.1`. Your `{2,3}` clauses are too restrictive.

Comment: Also, acceptable port range is 1-65535, so `{1,5}` digits, not `{2,4}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, no need put `(…)+` if you just testing.
Also you've limited 3rd and 4th numbers to 2+, but there could be numbers lower than 10 as well as the port could be greater than 9999.

```
var regexServer = /^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\:[0-9]{2,4}$/
```

Also, this regex only checks if correct format, but not validating the ip (checks if the numbers is between 0-255). Here is some more regex (without the port check, you can add it by your self):

```
var regexServer = /^(([2]([0-4][0-9]|[5][0-5])|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])[.]){3}(([2]([0-4][0-9]|[5][0-5])|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]))$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Whats your problem?

I see two things

```
/^([0-9]{2,3})+\.([0-9]{2,3})+\.([0-9]{2,3})+\.([0-9]{2,3})+\:[0-9]{2,4}$/
              ^              ^              ^              ^
                                                            ^
```

- The quantifiers in my first row of markers are wrong.
- The escaping marked in the second row is not needed, since ":" is not a special character.

Comment: Thanks for reply!

I'm totally confused... I started everything from the beginning, and I tried this:

var regexServer = /^[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]:[0-9]$/;

I only want to allow correct IP and port addresse's like this one:

88.77.66.55:8000

Sorry for my english but I took an arrow in the knee...

Answer (score 1):

You accept IP numbers from 10 to 255, maybe you should change the quantifiers from {2,3} to {1,3}, or else IP addresses like 128.0.0.1:80 will be rejected.

Answer (score 1):

I think your RegExp isn't working because the `+` characters.

This should work and is in my opinion a more efficient regular expression: `/^([0-9]{1,3}(\.?)){4}:[0-9]{2,5}$/`

You should allow 1 number for each level. For example: `82.176.103.6` wouldn't match if you didn't. Also, the amount of numbers for ports should be 5 because the highest port number is `65535`

Comment: +1 but `^((\d{1,3})[\.:]){4}\d{2,5}$` might be better because current regex also match `66.778899:8000`

Comment: @micha very good point, +1! However, your query would match `11:22:33:44` as well ;)